# Find out if computer started via Wake-on-LAN or power button?

Tags: linux, boot, ethernet, wake-on-lan

Is there any (reliable) way to find out if the PC booted because of a Wake-on-LAN Packet instead of pressing the power button? I want automatically check if WOL is correctly configured.

I know about `ethtool`'s WOL output, but this just tells me if WOL is turned on, not how the PC booted, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Manually testing using `etherwake`

I think you can test it using a tool like `etherwake`. Depending on the distro it's called `etherwake` on Ubuntu/Debian, `ether-wake` on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora. I had it installed already by default on Fedora, it's part of the net-tools package.

To use it:

```
# Redhat
$ ether-wake 00:11:22:33:44:55

# Debian/Ubuntu
$ etherwake 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

To confirm that a server support WOL:

```
$ ethtool eth0

Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ ]
    Supported link modes:
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
       Wake-on: g
    Link detected: yes
```

The "Supports Wake-on: g" and "Wake-on: g" tell you that the card is configured for WOL support. If it's missing you can add it to the `ifcfg-eth0` config. file like so:

```
ETHTOOL_OPTS="wol g"
```

#### Using `hwinfo`

I noticed that if you look through the `hwinfo` there are messages regarding how the system came out of power save mode. Also there are messages related to the ethernet device coming up. For example:

```
  <6>[721194.499752] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
  <7>[721194.499757] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: PME# disabled
  <7>[721194.499831] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
  <6>[721194.574306] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
  <6>[721194.576330] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
```

Here are some other messages a little while later:

```
  <6>[721197.226679] PM: resume of devices complete after 3162.340 msecs
  <7>[721197.226861] PM: Finishing wakeup.
  <4>[721197.226862] Restarting tasks ... done.
  <6>[721197.228541] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
```

The idea would be that maybe there are some messages here related to how the system came up (WOL or power switch). You could add a script that runs as part of a udev event that could grep through the hwinfo output to see if messages are present for WOL vs. powerswitch. Just a idea at this point.

#### References

- [HowTo: Wake Up Computers Using Linux Command [ Wake-on-LAN ( WOL ) ]](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-send-wake-on-lan-wol-magic-packets.html)
- [ether-wak man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ether-wake)

Comment: This just tells if the card is configured for WOL but not if the system was booted via WOL

Comment: Correct, the 2nd part of my answer explains that. The first part shows how you could use ether-wake to manually make a server go up/down to confirm that the WOL is working. This was ultimately what the OP was trying to do by looking at the status.

Comment: To the downvoter, care to elaborate what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Unless your network hardware preserves some state based on the WOL wakeup, that you can read after the initialisation during the boot process, you cannot determine this.

I have not looked at WOL in detail since 2000, but the network cards I worked with at that time certainly did not have such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the power-button.

If you do not have an iLO/RAC or something like that, which can watch the machine while it is off AFAIK no chance.

I did not hear it, but perhaps there is some vendor-specific tool that can read from your network card some kind of log.