# How can I look for a process that wake my machine up from suspend to RAM?

Tags: debian, kernel, process, suspend

My Linux distribution is Debian 10. When the computer has been asleep (suspend to RAM), it may wake itself in random period of time. I want to figure out what causes this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

These are the options I know of from the top of my head:

- RTC alarm: `cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm`
- Wake on LAN (WOL): `ethtool …`
- Power up on Keyboard/Mouse activity
- Power up after power loss
- Power button press, obviously

All these options can be configured via BIOS/UEFI setup, only some can be read from within Linux, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78292/find-out-if-computer-started-via-wake-on-lan-or-power-button).

Addendum: I just noticed `dmidecode` may include the information "Wake-up Type" (says "Power Switch" on my systems) in the section "System Information".

Anecdotal side-note: Ever since kernel 5.x, one of my systems has become a bit overzealous when it comes to the WOL feature. It wakes up on *any* network activity (e.g. broadcast), not only WOL packets directed to that very machine. I was able to alleviate this by explicitly selecting a different WOL method (magic packet).

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I have learned power up of a computer is prerogative of BIOS/UEFI, not OS. I figure out that my keyboard spontaneously sends signal to a computer. It remains to find out why it does.